# Visual Studio 2019 cannot find header file afxdlgs.h and afxdisp.h even though they are present on the system

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, atl

I have an old c++ shared library project that successfully compiled on vs2007 but fails to specific header files i have on the system. (afxdlgs.h and afxdisp.h)
[screenshot specific code segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgHqc.png)

I have installed all the needed visual studio compoments
[screenshot of vs installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkY4c.png)

And selected the installed platform components in the properties tab [screenshot of properties tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLL90.png)

The file is present on the filesystem at **"C:\Program Files (x86)"Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\afxdlgs.h"**
and **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\afxdisp.h**

Comment: Create a new MFC application and see if this compiles. If it doesn't, then your Visual Studio installation is broken, or MFC hasn't been installed. To repair launch the visual studio installer and check the C++ ATL..and C++ MFC components

Comment: Try to change platform toolset to the latest, something like "Visual Studio 2019 (v142)" PS: Vs2007 doesn't exist.

Comment: In the third screenshot, I see you have not enabled the "Use of MFC", perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: @heapunderrun unfortunately that did not solve it.
SimonMourier: didnt help either.
My vs installation might indeed be broken as Jabberwocky said. it randomly flashes like 2500 errors when I change toolsets. though this is a clean install so i dont know what couldve corrupted it.

Comment: @waynecrescent I suggest you could try to uninstall `c++ mfc for v141 build tools(x86&x64)` and then reinstall it.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT this sounded ridiculous enough to try at this point. Didn't help. Since i have installed the spectre mitigated versions as well since the IDE references this line in the buildtarget definition. https://imgur.com/a/PVkDQsv